# Want to use more than one encoding in Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a Rails 4 application that has been internationalized.  My application sends emails for each language.  It was originally written in English and French.  Where I have French text I added the `# encoding: utf-8` statement at the beginning of the file.

I have just added Portuguese to my application.  In my mailer I have the `# encoding: utf-8` statement at the beginning of the file.  However it is not working when I attempt to send Portuguese emails because of the UTF-8 encoding.  I have changed the charset in those emails from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

I have the foreign text in the mailer instead of using the I18n hashes because I have some multilingual people using my application.  Each person can select the language they want to receive their emails.

Is there a way to have more than one type of encoding in a single file?  I have done online searching but have only seen examples where it has a single value.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: 7/3/2014 7:25 am CDT

Here is the error I got when attempting to send a Portuguese email.

```
I, [2014-07-03T06:44:38.810000 #31093]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms
F, [2014-07-03T06:44:38.812179 #31093] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.

The source of your template was:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /></head>
  <body>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.iktusnetlive.com"><img src="http://www.iktusnetlive.com/assets/header-speakers-pt.jpg", alt: "iktusNETlive"></a></p>
    <p><%= @user.first_name %>, sua conta de usuário GRATUITA iktusNET foi ativada!!!</p>
    <p>Você agora pode usar sua conta de usuário GRATUITA iktusNET com endereço de email <%= @user.email %> com nome de usuário <%= @user.username %>.</p>
    <p>Você agora tem acesso ao Webcast de Vídeo ao Vivo, ao FÓRUM de Discussão à Rede de CÍRCULO Social.</p>
    <p>Nota:  Tenha certeza que você escreva abaixo sua informação de login. Letras em Caixa Alta no seu endereço de email e nome de usuário serão ignoradas. Seu endereço de email e nome de usuário serão salvos somente com letras em caixa baixa. Nós armazenamos a sua senha de maneira segura. Ela é encriptada de tal forma que ninguém pode descobrir o que ela é, incluindo o Time da iktusNET. Contanto, se você esquecer a sua senha você pode requerer que sua senha seja resetada na tela de login.</p>
        <p>Nós temos uma Biblioteca de Mídia onde você pode ouvir, assistir e ler materiais de ministérios que ensinam mensagens de forma similar à ensinada pelo Centro de Oração de Tulsa. Você pode usar a Biblioteca de Mídia sem estar logado na sua Conta de Usuário GRATUITA iktusNET. Esta página pode ser acessada a partir daS PáginaS HOME ou MÍDIA. </p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Clique <%= link_to "here", "http://www.iktusnetlive.com/pt/invite" %> para Convidar seus AMIGOS para ingressar à iktusNETlive. </p>
    <p>Muito obrigado por ingressar à iktusNET e tenha um ótimo dia! </p>
        <p>O Time iktusNET</p>
  </body>
</html>):
  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:31:in `acctact_email_pt'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:134:in `update'
```

Comment: I don't think using UTF-8 should prevent you from sending mails in portuguese.

Comment: I have added the error I got when attempting to send a Portuguese email that someone in Brazil sent me.  When I attempt to open it it says it is a Western Latin ISO 1 file.  As you can see the charset is UTF-8.  Since I got a 500 error I have changed it for future emails to ISO-8859-1.  Will this take care of the problem or should I add # encoding ISO-8859-1 at the top of the view?  I did not have to do this with the French emails.

Comment: The problem is the file itself is not encoded correctly in utf-8. This is probably because the text editor you used to create it is not saving as utf-8 by default. A better solution would be to figure out how to do that, and use utf-8 for everything. (It's the default in ruby nowadays)

Comment: I will recreate the file and copy the text in the file the person from Brazil sent me.  That may take care of the problem.  I will test this later today.

Comment: @Slicedpan your suggestion worked.  Please put it as an answer and I will check it.  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding of the view file itself is incorrect. You must configure your text editor to save files in valid utf-8.

Marking the file as `#encoding utf-8` will not help since it will force ruby to (incorrectly) interpret it as utf-8 when it is in fact in a different encoding.